# How can I calculate the percentage of urea in animal feed?

Tags: biochemistry

I'am having some doubts in the calculation  that concerns the urea percentage in animal feed using the method AOAC $967.07$

> How can I calculate the urea percentage using the following data:

The formula is: $\text{Urea %} = \displaystyle\frac{1.0 \times A (\text{test solution}) \times 100}{A \text{ (standard solution})\cdot \text{mg (test portion aliquot)}} $

If ($A$) absorbance of test solution = $0.187$ and its correspondence concentration from calibration curve = $\pu{0.41 mg/5ml}$.

If ($A$) absorbance of standard solution = $0.502$ and its correspondence concentration from calibration curve = $\pu{1.09 mg/5ml}$

Sample is prepared by weighing $\pu{1g}$ in $\pu{500 ml}$.

What can be the urea percentage value?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more readable, did I write the formula correctly?

Comment: Thank you , but the formula must be divided by the mg(test portion aliquot) and not multiplied

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm editing it again.